# Responsive WYSIWYG editor in jquerymobile website and mobile app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, response, wysiwyg, rich-text-editor

I'm struggling but i couldn't find a single rich text editor which is compatible with jquerymobile and Cordova.

I Have a container div now i want to put editor in it and the width and height of editor should change if container div width and height change i Have tried many editors like TinyMCE but they are not responsive and i don't want to use bootstrap library. Please help?

Comment: You could use an IFRAME to show  WYSIWUG editor if its not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

This question was old, but not answered very well and I ran across this same problem earlier today. jHtmlArea can be used on a responsive page with a couple of small modifications to its source code.

The original documentation for jHtmlArea can be found here:
https://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/07/22/jhtmlarea-the-all-new-html-wysiwyg-editor-for-jquery

The original source code has migrated to GitHub: https://github.com/crpietschmann/jHtmlArea

To make jHtmlArea responsive, simply replace the init function code in jHtmlArea-0.8.js with the code below:

```
init: function (elem, options) {
    if (elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "textarea") {
        var opts = $.extend({}, jHtmlArea.defaultOptions, options);
        elem.jhtmlareaObject = this;

        var textarea = this.textarea = $(elem);
        var container = this.container = $("<div/>").addClass("jHtmlArea").insertAfter(textarea);

        var toolbar = this.toolbar = $("<div/>").addClass("ToolBar").appendTo(container);
        priv.initToolBar.call(this, opts);

        var iframe = this.iframe = $("<iframe/>").height(textarea.height());
        iframe.width('inherit');

        var htmlarea = this.htmlarea = $("<div/>").width('100%').append(iframe);

        container.append(htmlarea).append(textarea.hide());

        priv.initEditor.call(this, opts);
        priv.attachEditorEvents.call(this);

        // Fix total height to match TextArea
        iframe.height(iframe.height() - toolbar.height());
        // toolbar.width(textarea.width());

        if (opts.loaded) { opts.loaded.call(this); }
    }
},
```

Hopefully this will save someone else some time.

Answer (score -2):

jHtmlArea is a nice WYSIWYG editor

is very simple to use

```
// Turn all <textarea/> tags into WYSIWYG editors
$(function() {
    $("textarea").htmlarea();
});
```

You can download the library from here
http://pietschsoft.com/demo/jHtmlArea/

Comment: i know jhtmlarea but i want responsive WYSIWYG editor